# Do published papers always have to present an innovation?

Tags: publications, research-process

I would like to publish a/some papers online. But do the things I discuss in these papers have to be innovations. I am still a student and would like to publish a paper about aerospace engineering (especially attitude determination, control systems for satellites, GNC systems).

Those are not the easiest topics, especially as I am doing that alone on a voluntary basis. So does the paper I will publish have to discuss any innovation? I think publishing something where I explain how some algorithms work, which I tested my self, is much more doable. I could then just explain the algorithms (which already existed) and present their results. Would the latter still be considered as a decent (research) paper?

Comment: If you query the literature and find there's not been a decent critical review in the last ~3-5 years, you could viably review what's currently out there and use that knowledge to propose a novel direction for future efforts. Normally a research paper will have to put forth novel content/ideas/algorithms, or build on an existing idea in a novel way, like taking that predictive algorithm and improving it's efficacy markedly.

Comment: Online you can generally publish whatever you want, unless you would like to publish in a specific venue. But who is your target audience? Given [this other question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/61834) of yours, if you want to publish a paper online to increase your chances to be admitted to a PhD program, this would quite probably not work. Admission committees typically consider only papers published (or sometimes submitted) to known conferences and peer-reviewed journals (stay away from the so-called predatory journals).

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano, so a place like "researchgate" isn't ok? I am just a student doing that on my own, how can I get  published in such conferences or peer reviewed journals? + there are almost no conferences about the area I am interested / Willing to research. My target audience anybody who wants to read my paper. The main goal of my publication is to get accepted to pursue my PhD.

Comment: No, ResearchGate is not ok if you want to increase the chances of being admitted to a PhD program, at least in many countries. If you want to publish, really, join a research group in your field for your master's thesis: make it clear that you want to do a serious work and that you aim at being admitted to a PhD. Choose carefully the research group among those that are clearly active in their field and speak at length with the potential advisors about your goals.

Comment: The people who constitute the research group are mostly my teachers. And these people know my grades...(which are average) . Why would they accept me? I think it might be more interesting to do something which they are not aware of and then a litlle before I graduate say something like " hey have you seen everything I 've done? Without u knowing" So I d like to use that as a great surprise argument, so they can't say no. I u know what I mean?

Comment: And just just joining those people for my master thesis might not be that interesting.  I'd prefer doing a lot of stuff before my master thesis. So I already have a bunch of arguments and prooves as why they should allow me to pursue my PhD. And on top of that I'd like to add the fact that I joined a research group for my master thesis.

Comment: @privetDruzia I'd happily accept a student who shows *genuine* interest. But I'd look at their academic performance carefully, I won't take on somebody who will end up failing or otherwise be harmed by spending time on non-class activities.

Comment: Doing research is like almost any other activity: you learn by doing, by making mistakes and having a mentor correcting you and leading in the right direction, pointing out interesting problems, explaining what has been tried and didn't work, discuss possible aproaches. Going alone won't get you far (or even anywhere)

Comment: @vonbrand so where could I publish a paper before applying for a PhD in order to maximize my chances of being accepted? (As research gate doesn't seem ok and there are almost no conferences about the domain I'm interested in) I'm very motivated, but need a few tips in order to keep doing the right things so I can be accepted.

Comment: I would be more convinced by someone that collaborated with me or a collegue rather than a "surprise performance" when hiring potential PhD students. I particular because the quality of stuff produced by students on their own is usually (far) less impressive than they think. In principle that is OK: what would the value of a PhD education be if you could do just as well without one? However, students learn a lot more about doing real research from collaborating in a team, and those that learned more are more likely to do well in a later PhD program.

Comment: @MaartenBuis, So should I try to find a way to work on some project with a teacher before applying for a PhD (and before starting my master thesis) to increase my chances? Even if I will only graduate in one year and a half (if everything goes well)? But if I have a full-time schoolschedule those teacher might justg answer me: "How the hell would you like to work together with me if you have class every day from 9-5".

Comment: That depends on the local circumstances, so I cannot comment on that. All I can say, that I employ students in this form. They don't safe me much time, and I don't expect them to: It is basicaly an internship, though it is not called that way in my institution.

Comment: @MaartenBuis, Thx! I ll try that! asking whether it is possible to work on a project (next to my compulsory courses)is supervised by one of our teachers during the time I am studying an not yet accepted for a PhD.  + I ll do my best to find a way to publish at least one paper.

Answer (score 3):

> do published papers always have to present an innovation?

Not really, it has to make a contribution to existing understanding, and this  can be a very specific contribution in a very specific area. Look at this paper for example:

Gauthier, Joseph P., Eamonn P. Glennon, and Andrew G. Dempster. "Timing Performance of V2R3 Namuru Operating in Position-Hold Mode." (2013).

It provides a very useful, but very context specific, contribution.

Of course the problem which you will face in trying to replicated a paper like this is that unlike these authors, you lack equipment and data to write up such results. However, you could consider getting data from one of the research laboratories working in your area and trying to publish something with them. This could be something where you write up some part of the analysis, or, if you really know your stuff, you take the data they have and then do your own analyses. More likely than not you would have to cite them as you are building on their work/collected data and efforts.

Another option for you would be to do some sort of literature review, for instance, timing performance for GPS satellites: A review of the literature. Something like this would also qualify as a contribution and could be publishable. Plus, if you did it in an area where you would like to do research, it would serve to signal that you are serious about that research and also happen to know quite a bit about it.